# Inserir no value de um input type=“date” a data retornada do Select do banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Estou a pegar uma data do banco de dados e exibindo-a em um campo `input` no HTML.

Só que, para o cliente poder editar como uma data, preciso que ele esteja em um input type="date". Porém, parece haver alguma restrição no HTML5 nesse tipo de input.

Como que eu conseguiria inserir esse dado no input que quero?

Exemplo do meu código:

```
 <input type="date" class="form-control" name="" id=""  value="<?=$data;?>" disabled >
```

Comment: Como está a data no banco?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumindo que a data no banco esteja no formato YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss

```
 //data retornada do banco
 $dataTime="2018-05-08 20:25:22";

 //parte válida da data para inserir no input type="date" YYYY-MM-DD
 $data = substr($dataTime,0,10); //2018-05-08

 <input type="date" class="form-control" name="" id="" value="<?=$data;?>" disabled >
```

> para poder editar tem que tirar esse `disabled`
>
> - O `substr` retorna um pedaço da string. Para isto ele se utiliza de três parâmetros: a própria string, o índice inicial e a quantidade de caracteres a ser retornada a partir do índice inicial.

**Resultado esperado:**

```html
 <input type="date" class="form-control" name="" id="" value="2018-05-08">
```

Comment: Perfeito!
Antes eu estava convertendo o formato, pois no HTML ele exibi dd/mm/aaaa.
E eu só pego a data "2018-05-08", facilitando ainda mais. A maior jogada foi não saber que tinha que tirar o 'Disabled'.
Vlw camarada!

Answer (score 1):

A data tem que estar no formato `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Ex:

```
<input type="date" name="data" value="2013-12-01">
```

Comment: Obrigado pela colaboração, amigo!
 Porém, marcarei a solução  do @leo, por está mais completa e tratar também do PHP e a restrição do input.